# iphone blutooth device connection

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, connection, data-transfer

I have an app which has to connect to a medical bluetooth device to get data from that device. (Not to any iOS device).
Using which framework or class I can connect and receive data from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After you get an [MFi](https://mfi.apple.com/) license, you then have to have an Apple supplied authentication chip on the bluetooth device. You must create custom protocols to transfer the data.

The BT on iOS is locked down and you can only access simple AVRCP events inside an app, no data transfer is allowed, except using GameKit (which only works between iOS devices).

UPDATE:

If you are using a BLE device then you can checkout this, it is iOS 5 only though.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you planning to develop this app with a jailbreak device?

If not, you have to enroll the [MFI](http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/)(Made For iPhone) program, then you can define your custom protocol and use the ExternalAccessory framework to communicate with your device.

If yes, take a look at [Btstack](http://code.google.com/p/btstack/) project.